# how to modify every field of a nested document mongo?

Tags: mongodb, insert-update

so imagine I have the following document:

```json
{
  "_id":...,
  "data":{"a":[],"b":[],"x":[]}
}
```

I don't know beforehand which fields the subdocument `data` may have. I just know that every field in that subdocument will be an array

How do I make an update so that the object results like:

```json
{
  "_id":...,
  "data":{"a":[1],"b":[1],"x":[1]}
}
```

Constraint: Using only mongodb operators. One single update. Without knowing the fields inside the 'data' subdocument

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$data" },
            as: "d",
            in: { k: "$$d.k", v: [ 1 ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rT17eD22rWL)